# Agora.io dynamic key generating on C#

Tags: c#, agora.io

Everyone,
I have issue about generating Agora.io C# dynamic key generating.
Who has experience on Agora.io, please help me.

```
https://github.com/AgoraIO/AgoraDynamicKey
```

Agora sample github doesn`t have C#.
And now I am using C# Asp.net, So I need to generating Agora.io key on C#.
Please give me help.

Comment: do you mean you need a port of, for example, [the java version](https://github.com/AgoraIO/AgoraDynamicKey/tree/master/java/src/main/java/io/agora) to C#, or are you programming something with/against this API?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need actually need to use C# for this. 
You can use any of the provided libraries and just host the dynamic key script on a server somewhere and request the token that way.

If you are looking to port it to C# for some reason, this is the [main function](https://github.com/AgoraIO/AgoraDynamicKey/blob/master/java/src/main/java/io/agora/media/AccessToken.java#L111) to look at